# Necessary to update indexes if the primary key data type change?

Tags: sql-server

I have large table with many rows. I want to change the primary key from int to bigint.

My question is do I have to update/rebuild the indexes? Or is that automatically done behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are dropping and recreating the PK for the data type change and it is a clustered index. In this case, the non-clustered indexes are rebuilt automatically when the clustered primary key is dropped and again when it's recreated.

With a large table, you could manually drop the non-clustered indexes first and recreate afterwards. That way, they are only rebuilt once and save some time.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the only thing you need to do is to issue `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ...`. SQL Server will fix the implicit primary key index as part of the type change.

In practice you will need to plan for such a change.

1. In some circumstances the change can be done online by issuing `WITH (ONLINE=ON)`. (The default is to do the change "offline", blocking access to the table while the change is carried out.). However, depending on the type of index the change might not appear to be entirely "online".
2. You need enough disk space (the old and new key will exist on disk at the same time).
3. Are there foreign keys referencing the PK? FK ints to PK bigins are allowed, but generally a very bad idea.

If this is a production system the only responsible thing to do is to test it. If there is no test system then copy a subset of the base table to a parallel table on the production server and do the change. Check if normal production queries can be executed against the table during the change.

Comment: I don't believe one can change the PK data type without first dropping the primary key.

Comment: My upvote is for "2. You need enough disk space (the old and new key will exist on disk at the same time)."  Hadn't considered could fail because of disk space for huge tables under (if can't change while PK is active, then drop, ALTER column, add PK back under a transaction).